# Is there a way to apply Bayes rules to this question?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

> Densities and conditioning on an event. Let $X$ be a random variable with PDF
> $$
> f_ X(x)=\begin{cases}  x/4,&  \text {if } 1<x\leq 3,\\ 0,&  \text {otherwise}, \end{cases}
> $$
> and Let $A$ be the event that $\{ X\geq 2\}$.
> **Find $f_{X|A}(x)$.**

I know that $f_{X|A}(x)$ = $f_{X}(x)/P(A)$

We can calculate $P(A) = 5/8$ by integrating or through area. What I want to know is.
Is it possible to make it like this
$$
f_{X|A}(x)*P(A) = f_{X}(x)*P(A|x)
$$

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to know is: is it possible to make it like this $$f_{X|A}(x)\cdot P(A) = f_{X}(x)\cdot P(A|x)$$

Yes.  Since: $~\mathsf P(A\mid X{\,=\,}x) = \mathbf 1_{2\leqslant x}~$ then:

$$\begin{align}f_{X\mid A}(x) &= \cfrac{f_X(x)\,\mathbf 1_{2\leqslant x}}{\mathsf P(A)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac 25\,x\,\mathbf 1_{2\leqslant x\leqslant 3}\\[1ex]&=\begin{cases}2x/5&:& 2\leqslant x\leqslant 3\\0&:& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $P(A|x)=1$ since you only consider values of $X$ above $2$, i.e. when $A
$ is true.

Comment: Why do you believe he considers only $X>2$?

Comment: Because $2\leqslant x$ is the event of $A$, we have:  $~P(A\mid X=x) ~=~ \begin{cases}1 &:& 2\leq x\leq 3\\0&:&\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Its a matter of semantics -- I would say we *consider* all $x$ but that because $~\mathsf P(A\mid X{\,=\,}x) = \mathbf 1_{2\leqslant x}~$, we get the desired result.